# Selenium/Razor App: How to get a button ID from first row inside list?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a list with several rows and columns. Each row has a button called "Show Trail Details".

[image]

During the test, i click twice on the "Date" column title, to have the latest entry in the list in the first row.
I need to get the ID of the button inside the first row.

The IDs are changing all the time. So its either:
`//tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/button[1]/span[1]` or `//tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/button[1]/span[1]` and so on.

I tried to copy the HTML, but it looks weird when i run the html code.

The inspect looks like this:
[image]

Is there any way how to get that ID?
Thanks!

Comment: are you to get ID value of 1st column or you want to click on Show trail details button on 1st row

Comment: I want to click on the first button which is present in the first row in the list

Comment: @SonaliDas any suggestion/idea?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get the ID of the button inside the first row.

But there's no "id" attribute on either the td, button, or span elements?
Or do you mean the '_b1_685ddfc4-de...' attribute?

If the id is just a means of getting access to the first button then you could just use something like:

```
WebElement firstShowTrailDetailsButton = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td[style='text-align:right'] button.mud-button")).get(0);
```

Comment: Sorry, i say ID to all locators. No matter if XPATH CSS and so on (i know its wrong to say ID to all types of locators :D). But i use XPath all the time

Comment: The `.get(0);` doesnt exist. I can choose `Count, Contains, IndexOf, GetEnumerator and so on`. And you gave me the CssSelector. Can you provide me please the XPath for that button?

Comment: any chance for another answer? =)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the notification.

    //td[@style='text-align:right']//button[contains(@class, 'mud-button')]

That would be the xpath.  The code is Java, it was just an example - essentially you jjust need to get the first WebElement in the list returned by the findElements call, so [0] for C#